# How to get dynamic generated id of a checkbox to see if checkbox is checked or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating multiple checkboxes with $.each loop and I am giving them the dynamic id's. On clicking the checkbox, I want to pass the Id of the checkbox to a function and see which checkbox is clicked and show the alert box "I am clicked". The data coming from JSON object "questions".

```
startQuiz = function() {
    $container = $('#container');
    $quizArray = '';
    $.each(questions, function(i, q) {
      if(q.id == $index) {
        $.each(q.options, function(j, a) {
          $quizArray += '<ul>';
          $quizArray += '<li>';
          $quizArray += '<input type="checkbox" id="' + a.ans + '" onclick="clickFunc(\'' + q.id + '\', \''+ a.no +'\', \''+ a.ans +'\')"';
          $quizArray += '" value="';
          $quizArray += a.ans;
          $quizArray += '" /><label for="' + a.ans + '">';
          $quizArray += a.ans;
          $quizArray += '</label></li>';
          $quizArray += '</ul>';
        });
      }
    });
    $container.append($quizArray);
  }

  clickFunc = function($id, $no, $ans) {
    $.each(questions, function(x, data) {
      if(data.id == $id) {
        $.each(data.correct, function(y, data2) {
          if($('#'+$ans).is(':checked') && data2.no == $no) {
            alert("I am clicked");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Instead of arrays, use objects whose keys are the question ID and answer ID. Then you won't need to loop to find the corresponding question and answer.

Comment: What's the problem? You're passing `a.ans` to the function, and that's the ID of the checkbox that they clicked on.

Comment: But it would be simpler to just pass `this`. That's a reference to the checkbox itself, then you don't need to look it up by ID.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I didn't get your point. Please suggest me an example or link which explains your logic.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. It looks like the code does what you want already.

Comment: I was suggesting something like `onclick="clickFunc(\'' + q.id + '\', \''+ a.no +'\', this)"`. Then `clickFunc` can use `$ans.id` to get the ID of the checkbox.

Comment: The above code doesn't show the alert box, but when i remove the " $('#'+$ans).is(':checked') " from if condition it works and show alert. I don't know why it doesn't take the Id of the checkbox with '#'+$ans ...

Comment: Do you have the same ID in multiple checkboxes? IDs have to be unique.

Comment: `a.ans` value is different for every checkbox. So every checkbox has a different ID. `a.ans` is coming from JSON object which is different for every checkbox.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for guidance. Here was the problem, it got it.

Comment: The value of `a.ans` was a string with spaces.